# Implications of a deterministic polytime prime-finding algorithm

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, primes

I'm wondering what are the current known uses/implications of a polynomial-time algorithm for the following problem:

> Given $n$ in binary, output a prime $p > n$.

I'm both curious about specific useful applications, and any more broad complexity implications (for instance, would this get us any closer to $P=BPP$?).

Edit: by the way, this problem was (is?) the subject of the [Polymath4 project](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Finding_primes), which produced [this writeup](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3956), but I do not see anywhere that they discuss implications of truth of the conjecture.

Comment: This is likely true since it is conjectured that the prime gap is O(log(p_n)^2): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture

Comment: @joro, agreed that it is likely true (although I am not sure if Cramer's conjecture is generally conjectured). There are interesting consequences of lots of things we think are likely true but cannot currently prove....